# How to disable a ts rule for a specific line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, summernote

Summernote is a jQuery plugin, and I don't need type definitions for it. I just want to modify the object, but TS keeps throwing errors. The line bellow still gives me: **"Property 'summernote' does not exist on type 'jQueryStatic'."** error.

```
(function ($) {

  /* tslint:disable */
  delete $.summernote.options.keyMap.pc.TAB;
  delete $.summernote.options.keyMap.mac.TAB;
  /* tslint:enable */

})(jQuery)
```

**Edit:**

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true
  },
  "include": [
      "js/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 352, accepted):

As of Typescript 2.6, you can now bypass a compiler error/warning for a specific line:

```
if (false) {
    // @ts-ignore: Unreachable code error
    console.log("hello");
}
```

Note that [the official docs "recommend you use [this] very sparingly"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments). It is almost *always* preferable to cast to `any` instead as that better expresses intent.

---

Older answer:

You can use `/* tslint:disable-next-line */` to locally disable tslint. However, as this is a compiler error disabling tslint might not help.

You can always temporarily cast `$` to `any`:

```
delete ($ as any).summernote.options.keyMap.pc.TAB
```

which will allow you to access whatever properties you want.

Comment: Accepted answer doesn't answer the generic question.  Disable a *rule*.

Comment: There is [an active issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19139) regarding `@ts-ignore` for a specific error.

Comment: and how to disable line inside jsx?

Comment: @Atombit Here's a GH issue with the solution to that: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27552

Comment: `@ts-ignore` isn't a recommended  solution, instead use the suggested `@ts-expect-error`

Answer (score 150):

#### `@ts-expect-error`

[TypeScript 3.9](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-9/#ts-expect-error-comments) introduces a new magic comment. `@ts-expect-error` will:

- have same functionality as [`@ts-ignore`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments)
- trigger an error, if actually *no* compiler error has been suppressed (= indicates useless flag)

```
if (false) {
  // @ts-expect-error: Let's ignore a compile error like this unreachable code 
  console.log("hello"); // compiles
}

// If @ts-expect-error didn't suppress anything at all, we now get a nice warning 
let flag = true;
// ...
if (flag) {
  // @ts-expect-error
  // ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ error: "Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive.(2578)"
  console.log("hello"); 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYMwBAFCCGA2DOBTAlGA3gKDGA9DsAAgC7wC0iAHgA6IDGR5ATowPaMBcYAMokQOTwwwAOYA7NojDQwtFgFsqwWJMTM2YWMADWkogAtgggK6jGiaLT3QARspksAJpKz3R8FsoB0sFsIgAiPURYH39kAG5cfFkFJUR4DABfDAw8MABJcGIyShp6JlZGMAdgB1E%20IjB4IyoqM3hBaFEAT31gUWEpSrhYABowAHdJcQGwYV4pMFFgWkkB6EZpjrAMZUqQWGhOgF4wIkYjRHDU-E8zjFBIDa3UTGw07PJqOgZVQpc0gD0AP1%20---%20nzAbzYnH8AFVREYkA4wHxHrkXgU2HxisAzPRgAA3RCeCAAJgArAB2AAcyH8Llkbg8uJ8fkCwVCERWiSAA)

---

#### What do TypeScript developers recommend?

`@ts-ignore` and `@ts-expect-error` are like a sledgehammer for compile errors. TypeScript developers recommend more fine-grained, narrow-scoped typesystem solutions for most cases:

> We added ts-ignore with the intent that it be used for the remaining 5% that can't be suppressed by any existing type system mechanics [...] there should be very very very few `ts-ignore`s in your codebase[.] - [microsoft/TypeScript#19139](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19139#issuecomment-690530124)

> [...] fundamentally, we believe you shouldn't be using suppressions in TypeScript at all. If it's a type issue, you can cast out of it (that's why `any`, casting, and shorthand module declarations exist). If it's a syntax issue, everything is awful and we'll be broken anyway, so suppressions won't do anything (suppressions do not affect parse errors). - [microsoft/TypeScript#19573](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19573#issuecomment-573271826)

---

#### Alternatives for question-case

▶ Use [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) type

```
// type assertion for single expression
delete ($ as any).summernote.options.keyMap.pc.TAB;

// new variable assignment for multiple usages
const $$: any = $
delete $$.summernote.options.keyMap.pc.TAB;
delete $$.summernote.options.keyMap.mac.TAB;
```

▶ [Augment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) `JQueryStatic` interface

```
// ./global.d.ts
interface JQueryStatic {
  summernote: any;
}

// ./main.ts
delete $.summernote.options.keyMap.pc.TAB; // works
```

In other cases, [shorthand declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#shorthand-ambient-modules) / [augmentations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) are handy utilities to compile modules with no / extendable types. A viable strategy is also to [incrementally migrate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html) to TypeScript, [keeping not yet migrated code in `.js`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html) via [`allowJs`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) and [`checkJs: false`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) compiler flags.

Answer (score 43):

You can simple use the following just before the line:
`// @ts-ignore`

Comment: sometimes you may want to disable eslint
```// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment```

Answer (score 40):

I used `// @ts-ignore:next-line` right before the error. As for reference visit the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments).

Answer (score 7):

If you're using `eslint` to perform your check or fix you can disable a line by adding this on top of the line

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/<RELEVANT_ESLINT_RULE>
```

Answer (score 1):

An interesting caveat I've encountered was when needing to disable TS for a particular line of JSX, where typically comments are meant to be enclosed within curly braces, e.g. `{/* @ts-expect-error */}. Here's a problematic case:

```
// Cannot place it here either
<MyComponent
  {/* @ts-expect-error */} // <== This will produce Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive.
  someProps={withTsIssue}
  // other props continue below, so we cannot make it a one line
  // especially with particular eslint/prettier configurations
/>
```

The way to fix it is to do:

```
<MyComponent
  // @ts-expect-error
  someProps={withTsIssue}
  // other props continue below, so we cannot make it a one line
  // especially with particular eslint/prettier configurations
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `tsconfig.json` just add:

```
{
  "downlevelIteration": true,
  "strictNullChecks": false,
}
```

and you will be fine.