# alternate response key in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular (typescript) project lint only allows camel-case but I'm getting my response in snake-case. Is there any way besides disabling the lint or getting the keys changed from the backend?

response
`{profile_id: 123}`

my model in TS `interface Profile{ profile_id: number}`

but I'm facing lint issues if I define my model like that.
I can only define it as `interface Profile{ profileId: number}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable a ts rule for a specific line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618878/how-to-disable-a-ts-rule-for-a-specific-line)

Comment: Unless you wan't to `any`fy all of your responses, there's not really a clean way to map the response object to your (lint-friendly) interface.

Comment: You could map your response to your interface using rxjs map operator, I don't think there's a way to do this automatically (unless you write your own auto mapper which converts snake case to camel case - there's some examples online)